# Error: Invalid parameter(s): status [rest_invalid_param]

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

We have been using this custom script created using woocommerce rest api ( php wrapper ). It was working properly.
But suddenly today, it stopped working.

```
[11-Jun-2020 08:27:11 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException: Error: Invalid parameter(s): status [rest_invalid_param] in /home/xxx/public_html/task/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php:350
Stack trace:
#0 /home/xxx/public_html/task/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php(386): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->lookForErrors(Object(stdClass))
#1 /home/xxx/public_html/task/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php(422): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->processResponse()
#2 /home/xxx/public_html/task/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/Client.php(82): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->request('orders', 'GET', Array, Array)
#3 /home/xxx/public_html/task/index.php(175): Automattic\WooCommerce\Client->get('orders', Array)
#4 {main}
  thrown in /home/xxx/public_html/task/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php on line 350
```

Our code is like this

```
$allowed_status = array('pending', 'processing', 'on-hold', 'partial-complete');
$param = [
    'per_page' => '100',
    'after' => $start,
    'before' => $end,
    'status' => $allowed_status,   
];

$ca_orders = $castore->get('orders', $param);
```

If i remove the `'status' => $allowed_status,` , it starts to work again but then it gets all the order.

Did woocommerce changed anything very recently in their code.  Any help will be appreciated.

Wordpress : 5.4.2
Woocommerce : 4.2.0